# Forking threads in VSTO outlook add-in

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I've a toolbar add-in that is intended to add selected mails to a very slow internal archive. At the moment I loop through each email one at a time, which is painfully slow.
Am I allowed to fork a thread for each upload from my add-in and then join when all done? or is that banned from within the Outlook sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the lazy question, for anyone who finds it in the future, there's nothing that prevents you from creating threads in a VSTO application. The test sub(s) below can be used to confirm this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim myData As String() = New String() {"a", "b", "c"}
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting")
    Using signalEv As CountdownEvent = New CountdownEvent(1)

        For Each s As String In myData
            signalEv.AddCount()
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state)
                                             Try
                                                 ProcessData(state)
                                             Finally
                                                 signalEv.Signal()
                                             End Try
                                         End Sub,
                              s)

        Next

        signalEv.Signal()
        signalEv.Wait()
    End Using
    Debug.WriteLine("all done")


End Sub
Private Sub ProcessData(s As String)
    Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString & " data: " & s)
End Sub
```